# How to retrieve the default value of a preference defined in the XML file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How do you get the **default value** of a single Android Shared Preference as it is explicitly defined in the corresponding **XML** file? E.g.:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="fulldb"
    android:summary="No selection rules apply"
    android:title="Use Full Database" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this..

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false); //default value if nothing is in the preference is the last parameter false.
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry folks, that's not what I need. The code sample is provided above.

Answer (score 0):

See below:
To Store the Value:

```
public static SharedPreferences myPrefs; 
public static SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();                 
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("FullResultIsOn", true); // value to store                 
                prefsEditor.commit();
```

Now to retrive the value:

```
myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    fullResultSound = myPrefs.getBoolean("FullResultIsOn", false);
```

Enjoy. :)
Thanks.

Comment: That's not it. The default value is stored in the XML file eg :
`<CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="fulldb"
        android:summary="if selected, no selection rules apply"
        android:title="Use Full Database" />`